# Functional dependencies and overlapping instances

Tags: haskell, ghc, functional-dependencies, overlapping-instances

I have a typeclass with a fundep:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class C a b | a -> b
```

I want to provide specific instances:

```
instance C A B
```

As well as a general, default instance:

```
instance C a D
```

Implementing this code as written, won't compile:

```
Functional dependencies conflict between instance declarations:
  instance C A B
  instance C a D
```

Switching to type families is no help:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class C a where
  type C' a

instance C A where
  type C' A = B


instance C a where
  type C' a = D
```

```
Conflicting family instance declarations:
  C' A = B
  C' a = D
```

Ideally, I'd like to get GHC to use the OverlappingInstances 'most specific' rule to resolve this.

I understand this is an issue that has been known for a while, with various hacky solutions suggested:

- [[Haskell-cafe] Overlapping Instances with Functional Dependencies (July 2005[!])](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2005-July/010685.html)
- [https://homepages.cwi.nl/~ralf/HList/](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Eralf/HList/)
- [Sound and Decidable Type Inference for Functional Dependencies](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2004/01/esop04.pdf)
- [Overlapping Instances + Functional Dependencies Unsound?](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4031)
- [How does haskell resolve overlapping instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038414/how-does-haskell-resolve-overlapping-instances)

What is the best recommended solution in current GHC Haskell?

Comment: There is https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/AdvancedOverlap which describes what you want, but it's not easy.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good reference! It's just a distillation of the hacks mentioned in the links.

Comment: What about a `newtype W a = W a`: `instance C (W a) ()`

Comment: If you flip the argument order of `C` you can derive instances via `W a` or `A`

Comment: @Iceland_jack I'd rather not to require wrapping/unwrapping of a newtype.

Comment: That is the standard way to add different behaviour, if you know the *a* type is distinct from *A* you can branch on that

Comment: Are fundeps intrinsically different from regular overlapping instances, where GHC provides a (admittedly ad-hoc) solution for resolving overlaps? It seems the answer is no. So this seems to be a gap in GHC's feature set.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is a *closed* type family:

```
type family C' a where
  C' A = B
  C' a = D
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking specifically for an open type family.

Comment: @AriFordsham What you're looking for seems like a footgun of type-unsafety and incoherence. If your specific instance for some choice of `a` (let's stick with `A`) is in scope in some places but not others, some parts of your code will think the associated type is `B` and other parts of your code will think it's `D`. A closed type family makes it safe because you'll never have some in scope and some not.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica why is it worse than regular OverlappingInstances, and GHC's 'most specific' rule?

Comment: @AriFordsham Because this lets you basically accidentally do a bad `unsafeCoerce`, and regular OverlappingInstances don't.

Comment: Do you now for a fact that this would be an issue? Can you think of an example? I would have thouht GHC was cleverer than that.

Comment: @AriFordsham Yes. GHC's cleverness is that it gives you the errors that it gave you. It's hard to give a concrete example because of that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232057/discussion-between-ari-fordsham-and-joseph-sible-reinstate-monica).