# How to import module hiding submodules or instances?

Tags: haskell, import, module

With this code

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.State

class DefVal a where
  defVal :: a

instance (DefVal a) => Alternative (Either a) where
  empty = Left defVal
  (Left _) <|> x = x
  x        <|> _ = x

instance (DefVal a) => MonadPlus (Either a) where
  mzero = empty
  mplus = (<|>)

newtype ErrString = ErrString { toString :: String }
  deriving Show

instance DefVal ErrString where
  defVal = ErrString "Default Error String"
```

I'm getting errors:

```
Duplicate instance declarations:
  instance DefVal a => Alternative (Either a)
    -- Defined at main.hs:10:10
  instance Control.Monad.Trans.Error.Error e =>
           Alternative (Either e)
    -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Error’

Duplicate instance declarations:
  instance DefVal a => MonadPlus (Either a)
    -- Defined at main.hs:15:10
  instance Control.Monad.Trans.Error.Error e => MonadPlus (Either e)
    -- Defined in ‘Control.Monad.Trans.Error’
```

Error disappears if I remove `Control.Monad.State` which imports `Control.Monad.Trans.Error`.

How can I import `Control.Monad.State` hiding `Control.Monad.Trans.Error` or hiding `Either` instances of `Alternative` and `MonadPlus` from there?

I use `GHC-7.10.2`

Comment: AFAIK currently there is absolutely no way to refer to instances in import/export lists. You're out of luck.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728596/explicitly-import-instances

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Haskell 2010 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-1060005.4), section 5.4 says:

> Instance declarations cannot be explicitly named on import or export
>   lists. All instances in scope within a module are **always** exported and
>   any import brings **all** instances in from the imported module. Thus, an
>   instance declaration is in scope if and only if a chain of `import`
>   declarations leads to the module containing the instance declaration.

So it's *dictated by the standard* that you **cannot** do what you are trying to do.

The reason is that by allowing this it would be possible to create programs that mix different instances producing incorrect results.

See [Explicitly import instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728596/explicitly-import-instances) for example.

There are some extensions (e.g. `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`, see [Breaking Data.Set integrity without GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735274/breaking-data-set-integrity-without-generalizednewtypederiving)) that allow to mix instances even without instances in the export/import lists.

In fact GHC already doesn't adhere 100% to the standard on this and allows malformed programs. It doesn't globally check for instance declarations, but only that only one instance is in scope where it is needed. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12744568/510937).

---

In your case you probably should use some `newtype` around `Either` to avoid mixing the instances:

```
newtype MyEither e a = MyEither {runMyEither :: Either e a}


instance (DefVal a) => Alternative (MyEither a) where
  empty = MyEither (Left defVal)
  (MyEither (Left _)) <|> x = x
  x                   <|> _ = x

instance (DefVal a) => MonadPlus (MyEither a) where
  mzero = empty
  mplus = (<|>)
```

Whoever wants a value `x ::Either a b` to act as `x :: MyEither a b`
can simply do `MyEither x` and then use `runMyEither` on the result.

Comment: If instances are always imported, hiding modules (if it's possible) won't hide them. Thanks for `newtype` advice!