# Haskell. Using constraint to define an instance of a class

Tags: class, haskell, instance

While trying to understand instances in Haskell I made this example. The Integer part works well but it does not work for the Float instance. I think it is better to make a single instance of the type Num (so that square works on all Num). I suppose I have to add Num as a constraint to my class declaration but I couldn't figure out what the instance would look like. As I understand it, the constraint on the class forces any instances to be of that type (according to the constraint).

```
class Square a where
    area :: a -> a

instance Square Integer where
    area a = a*a

instance Square Float where
    area a = a*a
```

Comment: That `Square Float` instance should work just fine. What problem a you experiencing with it?

Comment: The above code should work fine for Float. You should just call, for example area 10.0::Float to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I think it is better to make a single instance of the type `Num`...

Not really, unless you want to define that class *only* for `Num` types (and then you don't need a class at all, just make it `area :: Num a => a->a` as a top-level function).

Here's the way to make such a generic instance:

```
instance (Num a) => Square a where
  area a = a*a
```

This is not Haskell98, but it does work with the widely used `-XFlexibleInstances` and `-XUndecidableInstances` extensions.

Problem: if you then also want to add, say,

```
instance Square String where
  area str = concat $ replicate (length str) str
```

you have two *overlapping instances*. And that's a problem: in general, the compiler can't decide which of two such instances is the right one. Again GHC has extensions to make the best guess (`-XOverlappingInstances` and `-XIncoherentInstances`), but unlike `Flexible/UndecidableInstances` these are [generally avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830757/is-there-a-list-of-ghc-extensions-that-are-considered-safe).

Therefore I *would* recommend making individual instances `Square Int`, `Square Integer`, `Square Double`. They're not, like, hard to write, are they?